# Load portion of page preserving styles

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I want to load a portion of a page (table), preserve the css styles and load this portion into another page (same domain). An iframe loads the entire page with the styles. jQuery .load loads a portion of the page but doesn't preserve the styles. I want to have the best of both worlds..

an example:
[image]

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: If the two pages are in the same domain, you can get the code using XHR and insert the html code of the sub-page directly to the main-page, instead of using `iframe`.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not an easy task. You could extract the `<link rel="stylesheet">` and `<style>` elements from the portion, request external CSS files, determine which of the rules are applicable and apply each of those rules manually (using `.css()`) to the destination element. This could of course lead to conflicts with the existing CSS on the current page, so I think there is no out-of-the-box solution.